# Embed "HTML with JavaScript" in VF page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, api

### Background

I am working on payment gateway implementation on Salesforce sites using [Ingenico](https://epayments.developer-ingenico.com/payment-methods/view-by-payment-product/) with 3D secure. I am using the API which returns a response if the card is 3D enabled. Response will open a pop-up or new window that has a 3D challenge simulation, normally what a user would see with real transaction.

### Problem

If I embed the response in `<apex:outputText escape='false' value='{!response}'>` field nothing happens.
Upon taking the response out from debug log and use it as a separate HTML it runs fine as shown below.

> Desired 3-D simulation output

---

[image]

**Workarounds tried**

1. If I display the response in a `<div>` it shows as a string, rather than an embedded HTML.

**e.g.**

```
<div id="responsediv">
    {!response}
</div>
```

**output**(rendered as String, not HTML)

```
<form id="downloadform3D" name="downloadform3D" method="post" 
action="https&#58;//simulator.v-psp.com/SchemeAcsSimulator/acs/checkauthentication&#63;parameters=Z0SVV7Alrd81dLxvi035PXn0tUA3CRmBedfFWYKijnU%3d"  >
<noscript>
<div>JavaScript is currently disabled or is not supported by your browser<br/>
Please click on the &quot;Continue&quot; button to continue the processing of your 3-D secure transaction.<br/>
<input class="ncol" type="submit" value="Continue" id="submit1" name="submit1" />
</div>

</noscript>
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="CSRFKEY" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" >
...
<input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
</div>
</form>

<form method="post" action="order_agree.asp" name="uploadForm3D" id="uploadForm3D">
<input type="hidden" name="CSRFKEY" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" >
...
...
<input type="hidden" name="hash_param_3D" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
</form>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript" >
<!--
var popupWin;
var submitpopupWin = 0;

function LoadPopup() {
    if (self.name == null)  {
        self.name = "ogoneMain";
    }
    popupWin = window.open('about:blank', 'popupWin', 'height=400, width=390, status=yes, dependent=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no');
    if (popupWin != null) {
        if  (!popupWin &#124;&#124; popupWin.closed) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            if (!popupWin.opener &#124;&#124; popupWin.opener == null) {
                popupWin.opener = self;
            }
            self.document.forms.downloadform3D.target = 'popupWin';
            if (submitpopupWin == 1) {
                self.document.forms.downloadform3D.submit();
            }
            popupWin.focus();
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
    self.document.forms.downloadform3D.submit();
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

2. I removed the `<noscript>` in apex, so the user can manually interact and submit the form, button gets displayed but **nothing happens**.

---

My question is, how can I embed **HTML with JavaScript** in the VF page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the fact that the characters in the JavaScript were getting escaped, hence the form was not displaying / submitting properly.

**Example**

`if  (!popupWin &#124;&#124; popupWin.closed) {`

**should have been**

`if  (!popupWin || popupWin.closed) {`

After just replacing the escaped characters in the JS part, form was submitted properly.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include the full `escape="false"` example, but you'd be on the right track. This should work:

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!response}" />
```

Comment: I guess that SF is blocking form submission? :-\

Comment: @Mahmood Are you sure the code wasn't escaped in Apex (double-escaped, basically)? Have you tried using `response.unescapeHtml4()`?

Comment: Yeah, actually I used both methods, `unescapedHTML4()` and `EncodingUtil.urlDecode()` because some characters were not getting unescaped. That didn't work. I have both methods already in my apex in fact. Btw `outputText escaped=false` shouldve taken care of that, no?

Comment: @Mahmood Not if it was already escaped. What does it look like in the debug log?

Comment: I have updated the **response** with exactly how I am getting in the logs, Ids and field values removed.